# How to show opus number in main header and not in score headers?

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to engrave a sonata in three movements. I want to indicate the opus number only in the main `\header` block, but not in each separate score `\header` block.

So far, I've only been able to achieve showing the opus number in the score `\header` block, but not in the main `\header` block.

Code:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\paper {
    #(define fonts
        (set-global-fonts
            #:roman "Bodoni* 06"
            #:music "beethoven"
            #:brace "beethoven"
        )
    )
    print-all-headers = ##t
}

\header {
    title = "S O N A T A."
    opus = "Op. 79"
    composer = "L. van Beethoven"
    tagline = ##f
}

\book {
    % MOVEMENT 1
    \score {
        \header {
            title = "I."
            subtitle = ##f
            composer = ##f
        }
        \new PianoStaff \with { instrumentName = \markup { \huge \bold "25." }} <<
            \new Staff = "up" \with {
                \consists "Merge_rests_engraver"
            } \relative c'' {
                \override Score.BarNumber.stencil = #(make-stencil-circler 0.1 0.25 ly:text-interface::print)
                \override Score.BarNumber.font-series = #'bold

                \clef treble
                \key g \major
                \time 3/4
                \tempo "Presto alla tedesca."

                <g g'>4\f-. <b b'>-. <g g'>-. \bar ".|:"

                <d' d'>2(c'8 b a g fis g b g)
                fis4(e) d8(c b a gis a c a)
                fis2 a4-. c-. a-. fis-.

                g8\f d cis d fis g a d, cis d g a
                b g fis g c d e d c b a g fis4\p r8_\markup{\italic{leggerimente}}
                d fis a d fis, a d fis a, d fis a d, fis a d fis, a d fis e d4 r8
            }

            \new Staff = "down" \with { \consists "Merge_rests_engraver" } \relative c {
                \clef bass
                \key g \major
                \time 3/4

                \repeat unfold 9 {
                    <g' b>8 d'
                }

                \repeat unfold 5 {
                    <g, c> e'
                }

                \repeat unfold 7 {
                    <g, a c> d'
                }

                <g, b>2.
                <fis, d' fis>
                <g d' g>2 <a a'>8 <b b'>
                <c c'>4 <c c'> <cis cis'> 
            }
        >>

        \layout {}
    }
}
```

Result:

The "Op. 79" appears below the I. header, and not below the SONATA. header

[image: the "Op. 79" appears below the I. header, and not below the SONATA. header]

How do I make sure that the opus number appears below the title of the whole piece, and not the title of the movement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but I would do something like this:

```
\version "2.22.2"

\paper {
    print-all-headers = ##t
}

\header {
    tagline = ##f
}

\book {
    % MOVEMENT 1
    \score {
        \header {
            title = "S O N A T A."
            opus = "Op. 79"
            composer = "L. van Beethoven"
            subtitle = "I."
        }
        { c'4 4 4 4 }
    }
    % MOVEMENT 2
    \score {
        \header {
            opus = ##f
            composer = ##f
            subtitle = "II."
        }
        { c'4 4 4 4 }
    }
}
```

Put everything in the first movement's header (I use subtitle here) and then only the subtitle in the subsequent movements.

(By the way, it's nice to have a *minimal* working example of the code you're working on when you post.)